# Does Laravel observer needs its own DB transactions?

Tags: laravel

I have a pretty big system that use observer to update my database. My question is, does the observer needs its own db transaction? Or will it use the same transaction in the controller that trigger the events?

I had very rare issues with deadlock. The direct deadlock solution is to just include reattempt argument in the DB::transaction method. But the deadlock happens in my observer (which i didn't use db transaction in it) instead of the controller function.

Comment: The events should be fired while the transaction is still running normally, however if your event handler also contains a critical section (one that must be done atomically) then you should wrap it in a transaction as well. If there's a transaction already running (and depending on the DBMS) then either a subtransaction starts or nothing happens. However this should also cover you in the cases where the event is triggered outside of a transaction